# Why did my MacBook Pro just lose 30gb of space after I cleared out 37gb and hour ago?

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

I freed up some space on my 2017 MBP this afternoon. I had 7gb so I deleted 30gb to make some room. Came back to my MBP a few hours later and 30gb of space (and counting) was used up again. How does this happen and how do I stop it? I am watching gb drop at a steady pace and I don't know why. Help is much appreciated, as always.

Now my available storage has dropped to 1.82gb - what is happening???